# Java code not hitting IF or ELSE in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am running Android Studio and setting breakpoints, but on both of my IF...ELSE conditions, the code is not being executed. It seems to me that such a thing is impossible. Either the IF or the ELSE should be true... right?

The code is this:

```
       if (lastReading.isItTimeYet(Calendar.getInstance()))
        {
            lastReadingReturn = lastReading.SensorReadingChanges(z_value, chkOrient, inclination, rotation);
            if (lastReadingReturn.isEmpty())
            {
                String EMPTY = "TRUE";
                // DO NOTHING
            }
            else
            {
                int stopHERE = 0;
            }
        }
```

lastReadingReturn is a string. It is getting a value from SensorReadingChanges just fine. I don't see any errors being thrown.

I put break points on both the `String EMPTY = "TRUE";` line and the  `int stopHERE = 0;` line, but neither is hit. I can stop on the line before the if. But when I try to step into or step over the next line, the debugger jumps to the first line of code that is OUT of the If clause. In other words, it just skips it.

I have run it with both conditions (i.e. the string being checked is empty and the string being checked has a value) but it doesn't matter. Neither is hit.

Here is a screenshot of my Android Studio running in debugger:

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio]

Comment: Probably issue with the first if statement

Comment: The problem must be thaSegmentation fault (Core dumped).

Comment: Is this code really deployed?

Comment: what could be the checked in lastReadingReturn? instead of bare else, can you try with else if(lastReadingReturn.someOtherCheck)?

Comment: yes adding @Invexity it is false

Comment: @Z̷͙̗̻͖̣̹͉̫̬̪̖̤͆ͤ̓ͫͭ̀̐͜͞ͅͅαлγo Where do you see evidence of a segfault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your if-block and your else-block contains code that is very likely to be removed by the compiler during optimization since they actually don't *do* anything.

Try replacing them with something that actually does something like logging a message or move the declaration of `EMPTY` and `stopHERE` outside of their respective blocks.

```
   String EMPTY;
   int stopHERE;
   if (lastReading.isItTimeYet(Calendar.getInstance()))
    {
        lastReadingReturn = lastReading.SensorReadingChanges(z_value, chkOrient, inclination, rotation);
        if (lastReadingReturn.isEmpty())
        {
            EMPTY = "TRUE";
            // DO NOTHING
            System.out.println("Doing nothing");
        }
        else
        {
            stopHERE = 0;
            System.out.println("stopHERE set to zero");
        }
    }
```

Edit: Since I'm not being believed I simulated OPs issue in Android Studio:

```
final Random random = new Random();
if(random.nextInt(1) != 0) {
    String EMPTY = "EMPTY";
} else {
    int stopHERE = 0;
}
```

[image: Removed Code]

So, Android Studio is actually warning us that there is no executable code inside our else-block where the breakpoint is.

When run, this will only pause execution once, on row 18 (since `random.nextInt(1)` will *always* be 0).

Comment: do you mean that the debugger is not using the debug version?

Comment: The code inside those blocks is completely free of side-effects and removing them is guaranteed to not change the outcome of execution so it's likely that the compiler just throws it away and doesn't include it in the compiled bytecode. Since no compiled bytecode exist for the blocks it's impossible to pause execution there.

Comment: I run the following trivial code in myeclipse `for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
   
   if (x == 3) {
    int y = x;
   }
   
  }` and the breakpoint worked at expected.

Comment: Eclipse is not Android Studio though. I've updated with an example that mimics OPs issue and shows Android Studio actually telling us the issue.

Comment: Raniz if I could up-vote you 1000 times, I would. You are absolutely right! Thanks!